# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 'db-eshop.log_customer' doesn't exist,

Tags: magento-1.9, php, zend-framework

**There has been an error processing your request**

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'db-eshop.log_customer' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT * FROM
>   `log_customer` ORDER BY `log_id` DESC

```
Trace:
#0 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT * FROM `...', Array)
#4 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT * FROM `...', Array)
#5 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT * FROM `...', Array)
#6 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/design/adminhtml/default/admintheme/template/dashboard/index.phtml(221): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM `...')
#7 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/overleaf2...')
#8 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#9 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#16 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/design/adminhtml/default/admintheme/template/page.phtml(93): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#17 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/overleaf2...')
#18 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#19 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#26 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#27 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 /home/overleaf2015/public_html/eshopportal/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}**
```

> SQLSTATE[42S02]:Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'domain.log_customer' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT * FROM
>   `log_customer` ORDER BY `log_id` DESC

I was installing a admin theme though Magento connect but I found the above error. I already have a table name with `ep_log_customer` in my database. My admin panel is not working.

Comment: remove var/cache folder and check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your theme. Find `log_customer` in your theme and change

```
$connection->getTableName('log_customer').
```

The problem is Magento without prefix `log_customer` is the name. you are using prefix `ep_`. So no table in the name of `log_customer`.

In your Theme prefix code are missed.

Hope it will helpful

Comment: thanks for the reply. My admin panel is working now, but the admin panel header is not replaced with my new admin theme header. It is calling the old header file not the new one. Can you help me on this too...

Comment: Sure i will help you :)

Comment: I understand the problem is in admin header.phtml is calling from default. First you can check your theme header.phtml is called. if it is not called, create and call from in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

The code is looking for db-eshop.log_customer' table where `db-eshop` is the database prefix its looking for.

**Solution**

Search for the code `db-eshop` if it has been defined statically any where in code. If it does you need to replace that with your database prefix else if you are not using it remove it.

Comment: where i need to check the code? which file?

Comment: its difficult to say in which file the code may exists. You can use some editor such as sublime and  search in whole project if you dont know the specific area.

Comment: @MagicAkon also you can try searching through commands like : `fgrep -r "search for what you need"` you need to run this command in root of the site like cd /var/www/html/site.....